# Grails update template attributes dynamically

Tags: templates, grails, plugins

I have the following g:render tag in a gsp page:

```
<g:render template="/artist/rate" model='[artistID: 1, rating: 5]' />
```

In the _rate template I render a star rating plugin by RichUI:

```
<div id="artist${artistID}">
   <richui:rating dynamic="true" id="${artistID}" units="5" rating="${rating}"  controller="rating" action="rate"  />   
</div>
```

What I need is to be able to change the "model" attribute dynamically on run time.
I tried a very naive solution in which used JQuery to change the attributes. Something like this:

```
$(g:render).attr('model','[artistID: 1, rating: 3]')
```

but soon I realized that it does not work because the html generated from the gsp page does not contain the g:render tag, as it is replaced when the plugin is rendered.

Is there any way to achieve this?
Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a controller to figure out what the values of the model you want to render is and then pass that, the updated/changed model, to the gsp render tag.

The controller should be responsible for passing the correct model to the view, so do it there.